# Server Error Occured Appscript Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm rolling out documents to 100's of Users, using a Google Drive script. I have a lsit of Email addresses in my document and it should share the document with user named in column B and name the document of column C and then insert confirmed once done. I keep receiving an error which stop the script.

```
var Confirmed = "Confirmed";

function nxe() {


 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var startRow = 2// First row of data to process
 var specify = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
 var counter = specify.getRange("A1").getValue(); //HOW MANY TO DO 
 var numRows = 18;   // Number of rows to process
 var dataRange=sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 20)
 var data = dataRange.getValues();
 var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDERID');
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
 var row = data[i];
 var sheetName = row[2]   
 var FlexisheetSent = row[3];   
 var owner = row[1];
 Logger.log(owner);
 if (FlexisheetSent != Confirmed) {
 **DriveApp.getFileById('FILEID').makeCopy(sheetName,folder).addEditor(owner);**
   sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 4).setValue(Confirmed);
 // The cell is updated instantly to avoid any issues.
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
 }
}
}
```

It errors on this line
 **DriveApp.getFileById('FILEID').makeCopy(sheetName,folder).addEditor(owner);**

**Error Message:** 
We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 22, file "Code")

The script works but i have to keep running it.

Comment: Did you use a valid FILEID in the DriveApp.getFileById('FILEID').makeCopy(sheetName,folder).ad‌​dEditor(owner)?